# Distinct Real Roots of $2^{nd}$ order linear homogeneous reccurence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm currently being introduced to $2^{nd}$ order linear homogenous recurrence relations for the first time. I was working through a first example in my textbook and came into some trouble. Here is the section of my textbook:

[image]

What is confusing me is how they write $a_n = c_1(2^n) + c_2(-3)^n$ as the general solution near the end of the second paragraph. Why do we add our two solutions when it is clear $a_n = 6a_{n-2} - a_{n-1}$ from what we were given in the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want a formula for $a_n$ that doesn't involve other $a$'s, and thus allows us (once we know the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ to calculate any $a_n$ just from $n$.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I understand. It's legal because we are just saying there are two constants we can put in front of  our obtained values of $a_n$ such that their sum(or difference in the case of a negative constant) would be equal to $a_n$?

Comment: It's legal because a linear combination of solutions of a linear equation is a solution.

Comment: Okay, but isn't the equation basically saying $a_n = c_1a_n + c_2an$ meaning we're writing it in such a way that we know there are two constants whose product with $a_n$ will sum to $a_n$?

Comment: No, that's not true at all.  You have two different solutions ($2^n$ and $(-3)^n$), and every solution is some constant $c_1$ times the first plus some constant $c_2$ times the second.

Comment: Aren't the two solutions on their own? I'm definitely a little lost here.

Comment: What do you mean by "on their own"?  I don't understand what's bothering you about this.